# When using filepicker-rails, where should I define my avatar_url method within my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, filepicker.io

I've installed the `filepicker-rails` gem and I am able to upload files to the `filepicker.io` server.  When I try to display the image for different users profile, I get the error:

```
undefined method 'avatar_url' for nil:NilClass
```

Under my users directory, in the show.html.erb file I have:

```
<%= filepicker_image_tag @user.avatar_url, w: 160, h: 160, fit: 'clip' %>
```

I have the following under my User.rb file:

```
def avatar_url(user)
  user.avatar_url
end
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you'll need a column in your DB called `avatar_url`. Write a migration that will give you a `avatar_url` column as just a regular string column. Since you're using Rails, ActiveRecord will provide the `avatar_url` method for you.

Edit: In your controller you're likely not looking up your user correctly which is resulting in a method call on a NilClass in your view.

Comment: Shane, I already added the `avatar_url` into the migration.  I get the same error...

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I didn't read this correctly initially. `undefined method 'avatar_url' for nil:NilClass` indicates that your `@user` is empty. So in your controller, you're either not looking up your `User` correctly, or not at all. You're trying to call a method on an object that doesn't exist, essentially. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, before posting my issue, I tried defining the method 'show' with:
`@user = User.find(params[:id])`.  That, unfortunately gives me the following error: `Couldn't find User without an ID`

Comment: Ah, you'd have to post more code then, likely view code. For whatever reason, `params[:id]` seems to be empty, so it's trying to do a find without an id.

Comment: Shane, actually that was exactly the problem.  My 'show' method had `@user = User.find(params[:id])`.  However, when I changed it to: `@user = User.find(session[:user_id])` it worked!